Forall elimination and introduction using tactics in lean
I am studying the quantifiers chapter from "Theorem Proving in Lean 4".
Here is the first excesize I solved:
variable (α : Type) (p q : α → Prop)

theorem T1 : (∀ x, p x ∧ q x) ↔ (∀ x, p x) ∧ (∀ x, q x) := 
  Iff.intro
  (fun H : ∀ x, p x ∧ q x => And.intro
    (fun x : α => And.left (H x))
    (fun x : α => And.right (H x))
  )
  (fun H : (∀ x, p x) ∧ (∀ x, q x) =>
    fun x : α => And.intro ((And.left H) x) ((And.right H) x)
  )

#check T1

Here the proof is done by manually creating the term. Is it possible to use tactics to eliminate and introduce the universal quantifier? I found no examples of this sort in the book.

Sure, the basic tactics to use are intro and apply. Here is the proof written in four different ways.
variable (α : Type) (p q : α → Prop)

-- Using simple tactics
theorem T1 : (∀ x, p x ∧ q x) ↔ (∀ x, p x) ∧ (∀ x, q x) := by
  apply Iff.intro
  · intro H
    apply And.intro
    · intro x
      apply (H x).1
    · intro x
      apply (H x).2
  · rintro ⟨H₁, H₂⟩
    intro x
    apply And.intro
    · apply H₁
    · apply H₂

-- Writing down the proof term directly (kind of, we're using ⟨⋯,⋯⟩)
theorem T2 : (∀ x, p x ∧ q x) ↔ (∀ x, p x) ∧ (∀ x, q x) :=
  ⟨ (λ H => ⟨λ x => (H x).1, λ x => (H x).2⟩),
    (λ ⟨H₁, H₂⟩ x => ⟨H₁ x, H₂ x⟩) ⟩

-- The theorem is already in mathlib, it's called forall_and,
-- I discovered it by usign the tactic apply?
theorem T3 : (∀ x, p x ∧ q x) ↔ (∀ x, p x) ∧ (∀ x, q x) := forall_and

-- The aesop tactic solves it automatically (but produces an ugly proof)
theorem T4 : (∀ x, p x ∧ q x) ↔ (∀ x, p x) ∧ (∀ x, q x) := by
  aesop


aesop gives an error for me: "unknown tactic". Should I import some library?

@user4035, if you have mathlib installed it is enough to import Mathlib, but the minimal import to use Aesop is import Aesop I think.  (Of course it has to be installed into your project, and if you are following along with TPIL that may not be the case.  See https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/project.html#updating-mathlib-in-your-project.) The easiest way to play with Mathlib and Aesop is via the online playground but you still need the import line.
